# Is there a better and shorter way of my for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm a newbie here and this my first question. I learn basic c++ on Visual Studio 2019. I study functions and loops.

[I have a homework that wants print:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pB5U.png)

I solved it with my code of 30 lines. But I just wonder is a there a shorter and better way of this?

```
using namespace std;
int main() 
{   
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (j == 1)
                break;
            cout << "*";
            cout << endl;
            if (j == 2)
                break;
            cout << "**";
            cout << endl;
            if (j == 3)
                break;
            cout << "***";
            cout << endl;
            if (j == 4)
                break;
            cout << "****";
            cout << endl;
            if (j == 5)
                break;
            cout << "*****";
            cout << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a loop at all but some `cout` statements executed sequentially. In the second iteration `j == 1` and the loop will be exited

Comment: You never hit the `if (j == 5) break;` condition.

Comment: @Caleth It doesn't even hit `if (j == 2)`, because it will always `break` in the second iteration.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking `continue` not `break`

Comment: You have asked a very basic question, yet with a powerful concept.

Comment: you dont need a loop when the iterations have nothing in common

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have made several mistakes in your code.

- `break` statements should actually be `continue` statements. `break` terminates the entire loop altogether (ie. absolutely nothing will be printed in the code you provide).
- `i == 5` can never be `true`, as the loop terminates before thet happens (see the condition `i < 5`).

To answer your question, you can use a nested loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        std::cout << '*';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Or, if you don't need to be flexible, do it manually.

```
std::cout << "*\n**\n***\n****\n*****" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Oh, `endl` *does* always insert newline. My bad for misreading the documentation.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Nested loop has been my solve. However my code run on the visual studio 2019 but I understood my code is unnecessary work. Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Why a loop? Here’s the same logic in seven lines of code:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "*\n";
    std::cout << "**\n";
    std::cout << "***\n";
    std::cout << "****\n";
    std::cout << "*****\n";
}
```

To be honest, this is probably as short as it gets (apart from cramming all the output into a single statement).

But the issue with your loop isn’t primarily its length, it’s that your loop isn’t variable: it fails to work as soon as you change the number of iterations, and that defeats the purpose. All the logic is hard-coded, which makes the loop useless.

But if you want to use loops, then make the logic of printing stars configurable:

```
void print_stars(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << "*";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        print_stars(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: variation: `std::cout << std::string('*', n) << "\n";`

Comment: @Caleth That’d be the next level. I didn’t want to introduce any new concepts into the solution.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I like your void function and for loop. I'll study on this. Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    for(int i = 1;i <= 5;i++){
        for(int j = 1;j <= i;j++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
void printTrignleL(size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << std::string(i + 1, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```